# C++ quick sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm not looking to copy a qsort algorithm. I'm practicing writing qsort and this is what I've come up with and I'm interested in what part of my code is wrong. Please don't tell me that this is homework cause I could just use the code in the link below.

Reference: http://xoax.net/comp/sci/algorithms/Lesson4.php

When this runs I get this in the console:

```
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 10738]
Running…
Current language:  auto; currently c++
Program received signal:  “EXC_ARITHMETIC”.


void myQSort(int min, int max, int* myArray)
    {
        // Initially find a random pivot
        int pivotIndex = rand() % max;
            int pivot = myArray[pivotIndex];

        int i = 0 , j = max-1;

        // Pointer to begining of array and one to the end

        int* begin = myArray;
        int* end = &myArray[max-1];

        // While begin < end 
        while( begin < end )
        {
        // Find the lowest bound number to swap
            while( *begin < pivot )
            {
                begin++;
            }
            while( *end > pivot ) 
            {
                // Find the highest bound number to swap
                end--;
            }

        // Do the swap
            swap(begin,end);
        }
        // Partition left
        myQSort(0, pivotIndex-1, myArray);
        // Partiion right
        myQSort(pivotIndex+1,max, myArray);

    }
```

EDIT--
Code for Swap:

```
void swap(int* num, int* num2)
{
    int temp = *num;
    *num = *num2;
    *num2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: I can't see usage of `min`. maybe you need `int pivotIndex = min + rand() % (max - min);`

Comment: Show the code for swap()

Comment: +1 for resisting the temptation to cheat. Whether it's for homework, or for self learning, you only cheat yourself. I know it's cliché, but it's so, so true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// sort interval [begin, end)
void myQSort(int* begin, int* end)
{
    if(end - begin < 2)
        return;
    int* l = begin;
    int* r = end - 1;

    // Initially find a random pivot
    int* pivot = l + rand() % (r - l + 1);
    while(l != r)
    {
        // Find the lowest bound number to swap
        while(*l < *pivot) ++l;
        while(*r >= *pivot && l < r) --r;

        // Do the swap
        if(pivot == l) { pivot = r; }
        std::swap(*l, *r);
    }

    // Here l == r and numbers in the interval [begin, r) are lower and in the interval [l, end) are greater or equal than the pivot
    // Move pivot to the position
    std::swap(*pivot, *l);

    // Sort left
    myQSort(begin, l);
    // Sort right
    myQSort(l + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ya, i and j I was using them before for my array instead of *pointer. I obviously did not even have a base case to get out of this recursive function. I'm assuming it's more efficient to choose a pivot in the middle? No wonder when I had both while loops strong, the swap would just go back and forth. Can I ask why swap values rather than pointers? I always thought if you pass by value, it's a copy and not a reference? Thank you very much for your corrections. I now have a better understanding of qsort.

Comment: 1. No! The pivot should be in random place, because we assuming that array is not sorted enough, so possibility to choose middle value is same for all values, so the index should be random.
2. After swaping pointers, begin should point to place where end pointed before and end will point to place where begin where begin pointed, and this is not what we want in our algorithm.

Comment: 3. Here we don't have "passing by value". "Passing by value" is defined in function declaration, not in funciton call.`swap` signature is following `template <class T> void swap(T & arg1, T & arg2);`=>when we call it, arguments passed as references. Ofcourse we can't pass to this function constants.

Comment: That condition (`*end>=pivot...`) is dangerous. Use strictly "greater than" (`>`) instead. Otherwise you might turn the algorithm O(N*N) for the particular case of [almost] all elements equal.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the min parameter in your code, anywhere. You need to set begin and your pivot value using that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried working out the codes above. But, they don't compile.

@Mihran: Your solution is correct algorithmically but the following line generates an error:

```
myQSort(min, begin - myArray, myArray);
```

This is because `begin` is of type int* and `myArray` is of type `long`, following which the compiler shows this error message:

```
implicit conversion loses integer precision
```

Here's a working solution in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mySwap(int& num1, int& num2){
    int temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
}

void myQsort(int myArray[], int min, int max){
    int pivot = myArray[(min + max) / 2];

    int left = min, right = max;

    while (left < right) {
        while (myArray[left] < pivot) {
            left++;
        }
        while (myArray[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }

        if (left <= right) {
            mySwap(myArray[left], myArray[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    if (min < right) {
        myQsort(myArray, min, right);
    }
    if (left < max) {
        myQsort(myArray, left, max);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[] = {1, 12, -5, 260, 7, 14, 3, 7, 2};
    int min = 0;
    int max = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(int);

    myQsort(myArray, min, max-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        cout<<myArray[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The  loop `while (myArray[left] < pivot)`  can run away -> that is `left++` will keep incrementing out of the array bounds

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clear C++ implementation, for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int partition(std::vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    // set wall index
    int wall_index = low;
    int curr_index = low;
    int pivot_elem = arr[high]; // taking last element as pivot_element

    // loop through the entire received arr
    for (int i = curr_index; i < high; ++i) {
        // if element is less than or equal to pivot_elem
        // swap the element with element on the right of the wall
        // i.e swap arr[i] with arr[wall_index]
        if (arr[i] <= pivot_elem) {
            // swap
            int temp = arr[wall_index];
            arr[wall_index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;

            // move the wall one index to the right
            wall_index++;
            curr_index++;
        } else {
            // if the element is greater than the pivot_element
            // then keep the wall at the same point and do nothing
            curr_index++;
        }
    }

    // need to swap the pivot_elem i.e arr[high] with the element right of the wall
    int temp = arr[wall_index];
    arr[wall_index] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;

    return wall_index;
}

void quick_sort(std::vector<int>& arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) { // element with single arr always have low >= high
        int split = partition(arr, low, high);

        quick_sort(arr, low, split-1);
        quick_sort(arr, split, high);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data = {6,13,8,4,2,7,16,3,8};
    int N = data.size();
    quick_sort(data, 0, N-1);

    for (int i : data) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a clean implementation of Quicksort on SO, so here is my easy to understand implementation

*PLEASE DONT USE IN PRODUCTION CODE*

This is only for your understanding

```
// Swap position a with b in an array of integer numbers
void swap(int *numbers, int a, int b){
   int temp = numbers[a];
   numbers[a] = numbers[b];
   numbers[b] = temp;
} 

static int partition(int *data, int low, int high) {

    int left = low,  right = high,  pivot = data[low];

    while (left < right) {

        // Everthing on the left of pivot is lower than the pivot 
        while ((left <= right) && data[left] <= pivot) // <= is because left is the pivot initially
            left++;

        // Everything on the right of the pivot is greater than the pivot 
        while((left <= right) && data[right] > pivot)
            right--;

        if (left < right)
            swap(data, left, right);
    }

    // Put the pivot in the 'rigthful' place
    swap(data, low, right);

    return right;
}

// Quicksort 
static void quick_sort(int *numbers, int low, int high)
{
    if (high > low) {
        int p_index = partition(numbers, low, high);

        quick_sort(numbers, low , p_index - 1);
        quick_sort(numbers, p_index + 1, high);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Clean or not, first or not, this is not "production strength code". Not for worst case runtime, but for worst case stack occupancy.)

Comment: Of course, @greybeard whenever possible I recommend developers to re-use the STL qsort. My answer is for those trying to learn how quick-sorting works

Answer (score 0):

Easiest quick sort code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Quicksort(int *arr,int beg,int end){
if(beg<end)
{
int pivotLeft=beg;
int pivotRight=end-1;
int pivot=end;
int t=1;
while(t)
{
while(arr[pivotLeft]<arr[pivot])
{
    pivotLeft++;
}
while(arr[pivotRight]>arr[pivot])
{
    pivotRight--;
}
if(pivotLeft<pivotRight)
{
    int temp=arr[pivotLeft];
    arr[pivotLeft]=arr[pivotRight];
    arr[pivotRight]=temp;
}
else
{
    int temp=arr[pivotLeft];
    arr[pivotLeft]=arr[pivot];
    arr[pivot]=temp;
    t=0;
}
}
Quicksort(arr,0,pivotLeft-1);
Quicksort(arr,pivotLeft+1,end);
}
}

int main() {
int arr[10]={10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
Quicksort(arr,0,9);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
return 0;
}
```